# Angular 2 get user input in directive

Tags: angular, directive

I try to create a numbers / numeric input only directive, which means I want to allow a input such as: 451,45 or 451.45

Currently the directive looks like this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[numbers-only]'
})

export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
private el: HTMLElement;

constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: Event) {

 }
}
```

The next step would be to fetch the current value of the element, and reformat if every time on a key down event. 
My question : How do I get the current value of the directive, I cant figure out how to get it from the ElementRef. And what would be the best way to format the input: Regex ?

Thank you for your patience and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyup event, as this is when the value will be updated. And you do not need a `RegEx` for that you can just check the range of the `keyCode`. See this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xyAy2KjPia1qncqAcpMj?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts